# jquery / javascript hide everything expect div and its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I hide **everything** that is outside the class `application`? I want to hide everything that is within the body tag, but outside the `<div>` with class `application`. Is it possible? However, all children of the `<div>`should still be visible.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="application">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>title</h1>
            <p>Prompta habemus dissentiet quo no. Sit electram partiendo eu, civibus probatus euripidis at sea, usu admodum detracto te. No has dicta aliquid probatus, diam sanctus id mel, ne vocent animal eam. Cum an graeco aperiam concludaturque, ea posidonium contentiones sed, sed iriure admodum imperdiet ei.</p>
            <h1 class="center">title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try var element= $(".application").parent().children(); this will give you all the children of body. You can then loop over them and hide everything but application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no elements to hide in your example, but if there was you could do something like

```
$('body').children(':not(.application)').hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2wgvG/)

That would get all direct children of the body tag except `.application` and hide them.

---

**EDIT:**

If you have textNodes directly in the body, those can't be hidden as they are not styleable, you have to wrap those nodes in elements first doing something like this

```
$('body').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<span />');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2wgvG/1/)

only then can you apply styles to those textNodes.

Comment: And what about $(body).children().not('.application').hide() ?

Comment: @Superdrac both are same..!

Comment: But this only hides elements outside. I want to be able to hide. EVERYTHING. Even if it's just plain text outside? Is it possible?

Comment: Ok thank you @RajaprabhuAravindasamy ! And sorry for my stupid question, now, i know !

Comment: @user3151165 - Then be more specific, textNodes aren't elements and require different code.

Comment: @codezombie - As the OP tagged with jQuery, lets assume it's OK

Comment: i think, this will also catch `script` or `style` tags inside body?

Comment: lol, jquery is in the title so, yeah... It's ok! But is it possible to hide EVERYTHING that includes text that is not surounded with anything aswell?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I made some searches and It's not exactly the same ! .not() function is more slow. 

http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not the

Comment: @Girish - Does it matter, style tags generally shouldn't be in the body, and neither style or script tags are visible ?

Answer (score 0):

just use css for this

```
div.application ~ *{
  display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: That still doesnt hide text that is lonely sitting there without being within a div or something? It's maybe not possible to do this?